# What is the difference between \text, \textt and \texttt?

Tags: fonts

LaTeX has a number of different commands which begin as `\text` and then end in a differing number of letter `t`s.

What do each of the following commands do?

- `\text`
- `\textt`
- `\texttt`

Comment: Q.v.: `\mathbb` (Mathematical blackboard bold), `\mathbbb` (Mathematical bold double-struck from `mathalfa`), `\mathbb{b}`, `\mathbbb{B}`, and several others starting with `\mathb`.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 36):

1. The `\text` command is defined by the `amsmath` package. The purpose is to be able to write words or phrases in math mode.  It's quite similar to `\mbox` but has the advantage that it adapts the font size to the surrounding math style (display, text, script, scriptscript).
2. `\textt` is not defined by LaTeX or any package I know.
3. The `\texttt` command typesets its argument in teletype font (sometimes called typewriter or monospace font).  The trailing `tt` is an abbreviation for **t**ele**t**ype.

Comment: Off-topic.  Dumb terminals are called glass TTs.

Comment: It should be remarked that, when the `amsmath` package is loaded, `\texttt` also adapts the font size to the surrounding math style, exactly as `\text` does.

Comment: I was wondering what tt stood for.